# How can I process this JSON array to remove a wrapper object in each element of the array? using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I am not so into JavaScript and I have the following problem.

I have a **JSON** document like this:

```
{
  "forecast": [
    {
      "day-1": {
        "forecast_date": "2017-11-23",
        "morning": {
          "weather": {
            "meteo_forecast_id": 19,
            "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-23 06:00:00",
            "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
            "min_temp": 26,
            "max_temp": 31,
            "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
            "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
          }
        },
        "afternoon": {
          "weather": {
            "meteo_forecast_id": 20,
            "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-23 12:00:00",
            "meteo_forecast_description_id": 1,
            "min_temp": 33,
            "max_temp": 27,
            "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Mostly Cloudy",
            "meteo_forecast_description": "Mostly Cloudy",
            "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
            "icon_link": "Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "day-2": {
        "forecast_date": "2017-11-24",
        "morning": {
          "weather": {
            "meteo_forecast_id": 22,
            "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-24 06:00:00",
            "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
            "min_temp": 30,
            "max_temp": 34,
            "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
            "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
          }
        },
        "afternoon": {
          "weather": {
            "meteo_forecast_id": 23,
            "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-24 12:00:00",
            "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
            "min_temp": 34,
            "max_temp": 31,
            "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
            "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is an array named **forecast** that contains some object **{}** which in turn contains a **"day-X":{...}** objet containing some other fields.

Ok, my problem is: I have to remove these **day-X** object and put the content directly inside the main **{}** object.

So, starting from the previous array I have to obtain something like this:

```
{
    "forecast": [
        {
            "forecast_date": "2017-11-23",
            "morning": {
                "weather": {
                    "meteo_forecast_id": 19,
                    "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-23 06:00:00",
                    "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
                    "min_temp": 26,
                    "max_temp": 31,
                    "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
                    "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
                    "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
                    "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
                }
            },
            "afternoon": {
                "weather": {
                    "meteo_forecast_id": 20,
                    "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-23 12:00:00",
                    "meteo_forecast_description_id": 1,
                    "min_temp": 33,
                    "max_temp": 27,
                    "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Mostly Cloudy",
                    "meteo_forecast_description": "Mostly Cloudy",
                    "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
                    "icon_link": "Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "forecast_date": "2017-11-24",
            "morning": {
                "weather": {
                    "meteo_forecast_id": 22,
                    "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-24 06:00:00",
                    "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
                    "min_temp": 30,
                    "max_temp": 34,
                    "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
                    "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
                    "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
                    "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
                }
            },
            "afternoon": {
                "weather": {
                    "meteo_forecast_id": 23,
                    "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-24 12:00:00",
                    "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
                    "min_temp": 34,
                    "max_temp": 31,
                    "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
                    "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
                    "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
                    "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What is a smart way to do it? Starting from the original **forecast** array how can I delete the **day-x** wrapper objets and mantain theirs content into the **{...}** object elements of this array? I have to do it in pure JavaScript and I can't use third parts library or framework

Comment: filter, map or reduce

Comment: `obj.forecast = obj.forecast.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] )`

Comment: @mplungjan can you please show me an example about how do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` to iterate and return the first value using `Object.values` from every item in the array.

```
obj.forecast = obj.forecast.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] )
```

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {
  "forecast": [
    {
      "day-1": {
        "forecast_date": "2017-11-23",
        "morning": {
          "weather": {
            "meteo_forecast_id": 19,
            "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-23 06:00:00",
            "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
            "min_temp": 26,
            "max_temp": 31,
            "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
            "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
          }
        },
        "afternoon": {
          "weather": {
            "meteo_forecast_id": 20,
            "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-23 12:00:00",
            "meteo_forecast_description_id": 1,
            "min_temp": 33,
            "max_temp": 27,
            "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Mostly Cloudy",
            "meteo_forecast_description": "Mostly Cloudy",
            "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
            "icon_link": "Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "day-2": {
        "forecast_date": "2017-11-24",
        "morning": {
          "weather": {
            "meteo_forecast_id": 22,
            "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-24 06:00:00",
            "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
            "min_temp": 30,
            "max_temp": 34,
            "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
            "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
          }
        },
        "afternoon": {
          "weather": {
            "meteo_forecast_id": 23,
            "meteo_forecast_date_time": "2017-11-24 12:00:00",
            "meteo_forecast_description_id": 2,
            "min_temp": 34,
            "max_temp": 31,
            "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description": "Light Rain",
            "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
            "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

obj.forecast = obj.forecast.map( s => Object.values(s)[0] );

console.log( obj );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to read the file first:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/path/to/file.json', (err, file) => {
  const document = JSON.parse(file);
  document.forecast = document.forecast.map((days) => {
    return Object.keys(days).reduce((day, key) => days[key], {});
  });
  // console.log(document) or do what you want.
}
```

The `Object.values()` answer someone else provided should also work instead of my `Object.keys()` reduction here, but note that `Object.values()` has much less support as it's a much newer method.